# Creating consistent URLs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am creating a webapp and I have been using  tag in my JSPs to ensure that all my links (both to pages and to resources such as images/css) are always consistent from the root of the application, and not relative to my current location.

Some of the content I am creating using jQuery, for example, I am creating a HTML table by parsing a JSON object and using jquery.append() to insert it in to a div.

My question is, if I want to dynamically create a link using jquery how can I achieve a consistent URL regardless of the page being executed? I have tried just building the html  with the  tag in it, but no joy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var baseURL = "/* Server-side JSP code that sets the base URL */";

$("<a />", { href: baseURL+"/my/resource/here.jsp" }); //Your proper link
```

Or you could do:

```
var baseURL = "http://"+location.host+"/my/base/url/";
//Which gives you something like http://mySite.com/my/base/url/
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the root value of your webapp into a string using a jsp tag inside your javascript.

```
 var root = < %=myRootVariable%> //This evaluates to http://www.myapp.com
    var dynamicBit = "/foo/bar"
    var dynamicLinkUrl = root + dynamicBit
    var $newa = $("<a href='" + dynamicLinkUrl +'">Hello, world</a>");
    $someJQElement.append($newa)
```

Hopefully none of this will occur in the global namespace. Just sayin'

Comment: And there needs to be quotes around that `root` variable.